# Where is the code for a global variable declaration in Ollydbg?

Tags: disassembly, ollydbg, c

Consider this code snippet:

[image: sample]

I'm trying to find the code that declares the global variable in Ollydbg.

I can't find where it is.

Comment: Please note that you can paste code directly in any StackExchange site, instead of a screenshot from your editor. To add code markup, put 4 spaces at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 7):

The C compiler doesn't create any assembly code to declare and initialize global fundamental data types, so you won't see anything like `MOV ..., 3` in OllyDbg for your program above.

In the disassembly of your program below, you can see that the **global** variable is stored at `dword_402000`, which is hardcoded to begin with a value of `3`:

[image: Disassembly]